# python automatically change a variable from list to string inside a for loop

Tags: python

Python automatically changes a variable from `list` to `str` inside a `for` loop so I got an error when I append to the `list`. Why does this happen?

[image: error screen]

Comment: #1 post code, not an imgur image.

#2 you are declaring ug as a list, but later assign it (ug = group) if group is a string, next time you attempt to append to ug, it is no longer a list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your provided question and the output, I think that you are basically trying to swap the dictionary values of the given one.

So, the code for that is :

```
def func(dct):
  new_dct = {}
  for key, values in dct.items():
    for value in values:
      if value in new_dct:
        new_dct[value].append(key)
      else:
        new_dct[value]=[key]

  return (new_dct)  

dct = {'local': ['admin', 'userA'],
      'public': ['admin', 'userB'],
      'administrator': ['admin']}

print(func(dct))
```

I guess this should work for you!
Considering Upvoting if found helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just change line 14 to
`ug = [groups,]`.